# Google Gadget, Javascript (Or Other) Way To Port Collected Data

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-gadget

I am working on a Google Gadget that will collect some data through Google API's. What I am getting stuck on is how to collect the data and then save it somewhere to be processed later. The final idea being that I would run the gadget on my own computer it would collect the data and then save it to somewhere on my own computer. (I guess I want to emphasize that this is, for now, a small personal project and does not necessarily need fancy server scripts, I want to be able to run this all on my PC running XP).

Is there a pure Javascript way to save a file on a computer?

Can I use other languages besides XML, HTML, and Javascript to add functionality to my Google Gadget?

Edit: The goal of this is to be able to log how many of my contacts are signed into gchat over a period of time. I decided on a Gadget because that was the only way I could figure out how to access that information. Any other ways to approach this idea are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Javascript alone cannot save a file automatically. And be careful, javascript is affected by the no cross domain rule. If you're hosting the project on your own computer, why bother writing a complex Google Gadget?

I suggest a simple PHP script, and MySQL, if you like, to store the data. By itself, PHP should be more than enough to run most tasks. If you would like me to add in more info about this, please tell me what type of task.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what the overall goal is. To answer your question more directly though, in the sample gadgets google provides they already have much of the infrastructure I need to collect the info I want (see the TalkCommunication sample gadget in the Gadgets SDK). As far as PHP I was concerned that if I used PHP I would need to learn a lot of the XMPP stuff that gchat is built on, any thoughts on that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you would have to learn a lot of that XMPP stuff. However, how about using your gadget to collect that data, and then send that info to a PHP recording script, that records that data, either into a .txt file, or a MySQL database? For example, when your contact "John" signs, on your gadget makes a request to yoursite.com/recorder.php?user_signed_on=John , and your PHP script will log that name and the time it recieved it. Or you can just set intervals of when to check who is online, and send that data to a PHP recording script.

Comment: That was along the lines of what I had in mind, the problem is that a gadget is given functionality (from what I can discern) by a main.js file, I am not sure if the gadget will be able to run a php recording script.

Comment: You can use XMLHttpRequest to send data and commands via GET or POST to your server from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In increasing order of flexibility:

- The `options` object is almost certainly the easiest approach - not really designed for that kind of usage but I suspect it would be fine for your use case.
- On windows you could use `system.filesystem` to get hold of the WScript FileSystemObject which you can then use to create files and write to them.
- Also see the Google desktop API blog for [embedding an SQLite database](http://googledesktopapis.blogspot.com/2008/07/tip-embed-sqlite3-database.html) in your gadget (looks pretty easy).